# php mysql: can't get data from database

Tags: php, mysql

my code is below. I can't get data from table. Please help
database.php

```
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','filesproject') or die('Error      connecting to MySQL server.');
```

index.php

```
 <?php
 include('config/database.php');

 //Step2
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
 mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

 //Step3
 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['USERNAME'];
 }

 ?>
```

And nothing happens, just empty screen

Comment: Are you sure that you're actually getting data from `mysqli_fetch_array`? Maybe your user table is empty

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` that is definitely failing.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: A lot of problems can be detected and resolved by [enabling exceptions in `mysqli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so mistakes aren't easily ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You have both the query and mysqli_fetch_array twice in your code.

When you call the mysqli_fetch_array the second time, the array needs to be reset.

For simplicity, please try and remove this single line (not what's in the while loop) as it's not needed.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

More information on resetting the pointer in the array can be found here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: Thank you ! That was the reason of fail!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is acceptable - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove either while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) and  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result).

Answer (score 0):

there is to functions.
1- `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`;
2- `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`;
and codes are like bellow.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row[0];
     echo $row[1];
     echo $row[2];
}
```

and in this case

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row['USERNAME'];
     echo $row['NAME'];
     echo $row['LASTNAME'];
}
```

---

for case 1:
0, 1 and 2 are the column position in table.

for case 2:
USERNAME, NAME and LASTNAME are the name of column in table.